# TSQL: Need to Count Multiple Columns and Group by their Contents

Tags: t-sql, count, multiple-columns

I have the following dataset:

```
StartDate   EnterDate   Order#
----------  ----------  ------
2018-01-01  2018-01-01  1
2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2
2018-01-01  2018-01-02  3
2018-01-02  2018-01-02  4
2018-01-02  2018-01-03  5
2018-01-02  2018-01-03  6
2018-01-03  2018-01-04  7
2018-01-03  2018-01-04  8
2018-01-03  2018-01-04  9
2018-01-03  2018-01-05  10
```

I need to `COUNT` the number of dates in each column.

Example output:

```
Date          StartDate    EnterDate
----------    ---------    ---------
01-01-2018    3            2
01-02-2018    3            2
01-03-2018    4            2
01-04-2018    0            3
01-05-2018    0            1
```

`NULL` can be substituted for `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `full join` to achieve that

```
select
    Date = isnull(t.StartDate, q.EnterDate), StartDate = isnull(t.cnt, 0), EnterDate = isnull(q.cnt, 0)
from (
    select
        StartDate, count(*) cnt
    from
        myTable
    group by StartDate
) t 
full join (
    select
        EnterDate, count(*) cnt
    from
        myTable
    group by EnterDate
) q on t.StartDate = q.EnterDate
```